# Lookup method bug with SysTableLookup?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

This is code that should work with any base system added to Tables\ProdBOM.  Somehow the query is stripping out data from fields.

```
static void lookupItemIdBOMSubset(FormStringControl   _ctrl,
                                  ProdId              _prodId)
{
    SysTableLookup          sysTableLookup  = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(ProdBOM), _ctrl);
    Query                   query           = new Query();
    QueryBuildDataSource    qbds            = query.addDataSource(tableNum(ProdBOM));
    ;

    qbds.addRange(fieldNum(ProdBOM, ProdId)).value(queryvalue(_prodId));
    qbds.addSortField(fieldNum(ProdBOM, LineNum), SortOrder::Ascending);

    sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);

    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(ProdBOM, LineNum));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(ProdBOM, BOMId));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(ProdBOM, ItemId), true);

    // This doesn't work \/
    sysTableLookup.addLookupMethod(tablemethodstr(ProdBOM, configId));
    // This doesn't work /\

    sysTableLookup.addLookupMethod(tablemethodstr(ProdBOM, itemName));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(ProdBOM, ProdLineType));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(ProdBOM, InventTransId));

    sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
}
```

In the Tables\ProdBOM\Methods\configId, you can clearly see something is awry with this code.  What's going on??

```
//BP Deviation documented
display ConfigId configId()
{
    ProdBOM pb;
    ;
    select firstonly pb where pb.RecId == this.RecId;

    info(strfmt("Bad: [%1, %2], Good:[%3, %4]", this.ItemId, this.InventDimId, pb.ItemId, pb.InventDimId));
    return this.inventDim().ConfigId;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured it out.  In `Classes\SysTableLookup\buildSelectionList`, it adds all of the fields that are included in the lookupfields to the QBDS.addSelectionField, which appears to drop it off the return fields??

It doesn't strip out RecId though, so I was able to just create another display method that re-selects the record using the recId.

```
//BP Deviation documented
display ConfigId configIdFromRecId()
{
    return InventDim::find((select firstonly prodBOM where prodBOM.RecId == this.RecId).InventDimId).configId;
}
```

Comment: this just saved me from going insane - ever find out why this happens? Same in 2012 R2

Comment: I'm glad it helped somebody!!  I think I just cured my symptom and didn't bother to look back a second time.  I'm sure there is a good explanation but I'd have to dig and stare at it for a while.  You're free to give it a shot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can force the QueryBuildDatasource to load needed fields by modifying its fieldlist. You can use `QueryBuildDatasource.fields().addField()`  method to add fields wich schould be fetched and are in use by your LookupMethod