# Using AddLookupMethod

Tags: axapta, x++

I have a lookup created by code filled with a query on ProjTable. I want to add a field to this lookup that is a display method on ProjTable (displayCustName) that retrieves the name from CustTable for each customer related to the relative contract of the lookup.

I found that I could do this with 'AddLookupMethod', it adds the field to the lookup but empty. I don't know how to use it properly, any help?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this is related?
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843756/lookup-method-bug-with-systablelookup)

Comment: Does your lookup contain the fields that are needed for the display method?If not, the question you linked to provides the answer: You would have to include the fields needed for the display method in the lookup or rewrite the display method so that it first retrieves the whole ProjTable record using the RecId and then use this record to retrieve the display method value.

Comment: you should post some code, show what you have done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you linked to in the comments basically contains the answer, but it is not stated very clearly.

In short, if you want to use `addLookupMethod` with a `SysTableLookup` instance, you have to make sure that you also add the fields needed for the lookup method by using `addLookupField`.

Another solution would be to write your own lookup method that first retrieves the record of the table with the lookup method by using `RecId` and then use the data of that record to retrieve the return value of the lookup method.

```
public void lookup()
{
    SysTableLookup       sysTableLookup;
    Query                query;
    QueryBuildDataSource qbds;

    sysTableLookup = sysTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(ProjTable), this);
    query = new Query();
    qbds = query.addDataSource(tableNum(ProjTable));
    sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);

    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(ProjTable, ProjId));
    /* option 1: add the CustAccount field to the lookup so it can be used by the custName method
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(ProjTable, CustAccount));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupMethod(tableMethodStr(ProjTable, custName));
    */
    // option 2: write your own lookup method
    sysTableLookup.addLookupMethod(tableMethodStr(ProjTable, myCustName));

    sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
}
```

Display method for Option 2:

```
/// <summary>
///    Retrieves the customer name.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
///    The name of the customer.
/// </returns>
display CustName myCustName()
{
    ProjTable projTable;

    // the ProjTable record referenced by 'this' will not contain the field CustAccount
    // if this method is called by a SysTableLookup instance that does not explicitely 
    // contain CustAccount as lookup field
    // therefore the ProjTable record must be reselected using RecId
    select firstOnly CustAccount from projTable where projTable.RecId == this.RecId;
    return CustTable::find(projTable.CustAccount).name();
}
```